# How can I prevent a "Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute" when dynamically adding a column to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, resharper, nullable, notnull

I've got this code:

```
dtAddrInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", Type.GetType("System.String")));
```

...which Resharper barks about, saying, "*Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute*"

What is wrong with the code?

Even when I let Resharper adjust the code with its various suggestions:

```
dtAddrInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", dataType: System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
dtAddrInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("City", System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
dtAddrInfo.Columns.Add(column: new DataColumn("State", Type.GetType("System.String")));
```

...it still bitterly complains about the same thing in the same way on each of those lines.

It doesn't prevent compilation, but I still like to be Mr. Clean where possible.

Comment: What version of R# are you using? [This bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-207297) was fixed in 6.0 but not sure if that's related to your issue

Comment: 2016.1; but I just noticed it says "Update available" so I'll do that and see if I still get those warnings.

Comment: I'm now on R# 2016.1.2, and it still whin[g]es about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
System.Type.GetType("System.String")
```

can return `null`, because you are doing a `String` lookup of a `Type` that may not exist, you should use:

```
typeof(System.String)
```

Then it ought to stop complaining.